# Display package-specific commands with lst

Tags: listings, packages

I would like to display code similar to:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]

\draw[fill=blue!25] (-15,0) -- (-3,0) -- (-3,-12) -- (-15,-12) -- cycle;

\draw[fill=blue!25] (8,1) -- (14,1) -- (14, -5) -- (8, -5) -- cycle;

\draw[fill=blue!25] (16,1) -- (22,1) -- (22,-5) --  (16,-5) --cycle;

\draw[fill=blue!25] (8,-7) -- (14,-7) -- (14, -13) -- (8, -13) -- cycle;

\draw[fill=blue!25] (16,-7) -- (22,-7) -- (22,-13) --  (16,-13) --cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}
```

I have already found the command \begin{lstlisting}[language={[latex]TeX}], but this method leaves package-specific commands like \draw without turning them bold.

Any ideas for how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can add keywords for `lstlisting` using the option `morekeywords={}` with the keywords separated by commas.

Alternatively you can use the `minted` package.

MWE for both options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language={[latex]TeX},morekeywords={draw}]
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
\draw[fill=blue!25] (-15,0) -- (-3,0) -- (-3,-12) -- (-15,-12) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=blue!25] (8,1) -- (14,1) -- (14, -5) -- (8, -5) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=blue!25] (16,1) -- (22,1) -- (22,-5) --  (16,-5) --cycle;
\draw[fill=blue!25] (8,-7) -- (14,-7) -- (14, -13) -- (8, -13) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=blue!25] (16,-7) -- (22,-7) -- (22,-13) --  (16,-13) --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{minted}{latex}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.2]
\draw[fill=blue!25] (-15,0) -- (-3,0) -- (-3,-12) -- (-15,-12) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=blue!25] (8,1) -- (14,1) -- (14, -5) -- (8, -5) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=blue!25] (16,1) -- (22,1) -- (22,-5) --  (16,-5) --cycle;
\draw[fill=blue!25] (8,-7) -- (14,-7) -- (14, -13) -- (8, -13) -- cycle;
\draw[fill=blue!25] (16,-7) -- (22,-7) -- (22,-13) --  (16,-13) --cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]